# Integrate C# Desktop Application With Browsers

Tags: c#, browser, download

I have developed an application(downloader) using C# now i want to integrate it to browser like i want to place a button in browsers if user press that button then my app should execute & start downloading the required file.

Comment: What is this "button"? A toolbar? links in a web page? what?

Comment: yeah it doesn't matter what type of button is it. toolbar button will be great & easy to use.

Comment: that would require very different code for every browser, is not even necessarily *possible*, and is frankly frowned upon unless you have a **very** good reason to think your app is *that* important to the user's everyday browser usage...

Comment: ok then what about for only IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm largely guessing, but it *sounds* like you are talking about a "protocol handler", i.e. to handle hyperlinks to "yourapp:some-stuff-here". If so, try looking at [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN, which gives a C# example of this.

Comment: please check this link; i want to do exactly this. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MyDownloader/MyDwnloader10.png

Comment: @KhanZeeshan: It's a Browser Toolbar. You have to write an IE Plugin for that.

Comment: ok. can you suggest any tutorial for implementing IE Plugin, i googled it but i was hoping of finding something that will show some code.

Comment: @Khan - you mean like the "Download source" button [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MyDownloader.aspx) ? Or indeed the 10+ pages of code explanation in the article itself?

Comment: yeah but its so lengthy, anyways i'll read the explanation because i need it & code will be helpful as well. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you want is possible, you can however place a link to the executable and tell your users to execute it via the Browser download options (The Dialog that pops up when you click on some download link that asks wether you want to open oder save the file).

It is not possible to immedatly run your GUI application on a browser button click.